# How to run Node.js in localhost?

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

This is my first time to use Node.js and I would like to run it on localhost. I had installed Node.js, but I don't know how to run the localhost.

can you guys help me? Below is my server.js code.

```
setting_detail = {};
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
    var cluster = require('cluster');
    if (cluster.isMaster) {
        // Count the machine's CPUs
        var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;

        // Create a worker for each CPU
        for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
            cluster.fork();
        }

        // Code to run if we're in a worker process
    } else {
        init();
    }
} else {
    init();
}

function init() {
    var port = 5000;
    var config = require('./config/config'),
        mongoose = require('./config/mongoose'),
        express = require('./config/express'),
        db = mongoose(),
        app = express();

    app.listen(port);
    var Settings = require('mongoose').model('Settings');
    Settings.findOne({}, function (error, setting) {
        setting_detail = setting
        console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
    });
    module.exports = app;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `npm start`? That's the general way. I recommend you read the documentation first and try something on your own before seeking help. :-)

Answer (score 7):

You just need to run `node server.js` at your project path & then visit this -http://localhost:5000

**[Here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/)** is getting started guide for you.

Answer (score -2):

Simple Program for node

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Hello World');
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Source : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_express_framework.htm

for Mongoose:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications

Comment: The OP already has a program written. They are asking how to run it.